# How to convert spread operator so it is compatible with IE?

Tags: javascript

I am using a spread operator to filter and reduce the following JSON data so that it converts to a an object.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
    "HasAccess": true,
    "Presentations": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 5
    },
    "Articles": {
        "Instant": true,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": true,
        "ContentTypeId": 1
    },
    "Blogs": {
        "Instant": true,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": true,
        "ContentTypeId": 61
    }
}
```

Here is what the output is supposed to be:

```
{
  "Presentations": {
    "Instant": false,
    "Daily": false,
    "WeeklySummary": false,
    "ContentTypeId": 5
  },
  "Articles": {
    "Instant": true,
    "Daily": false,
    "WeeklySummary": true,
    "ContentTypeId": 1
  },
  "Blogs": {
    "Instant": true,
    "Daily": false,
    "WeeklySummary": true,
    "ContentTypeId": 61
  }
}
```

Essentially, I need to create an array of objects that removes that first "HasAccess" property. And this is the filter/reduce function I am using for that:

```
var result = Object.entries(data).filter(([key, value]) => {
      return value.hasOwnProperty('Instant')
   }).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
      return { ...acc, [key]: value }
   }, {})
```

However the spread operator (and by extension Object.assign) are not compatible with IE. What would be the best way to leverage the reduce function so that it could be compatible with IE?

A couple of notes, I know this seems a bit over-complex just to remove that first property and attribute. Using just the filter function without the reduce is not giving me the proper format, they end up having double brackets which won't let me read the data. My knowledge of objects is still a bit new so I'm trying to understand the easiest way to accomplish this.

Comment: Consider using Babel?

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: You can use `delete data.HasAccess;` to get rid of that property.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah I considered that, but how could I remove the extra pair of brackets around the object? That's been the sticking point.

Comment: "Extra pair of brackets" — what? That `delete` statement will remove that property, and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet for this sort of thing (in my view), is to use a ES2015+ to ES5 compiler/transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). Then you can happily write code with modern syntax and such, and have it output the ES5 equivalent for use in ES11.

But if you want to do it manually, include a polyfill for `Object.assign` (which IE11 doesn't otherwise have) and change

```
return { ...acc, [key]: value }
```

to

```
var obj = Object.assign({}, acc);
obj[key] = value;
return obj;
```

Note that there are *two* ES2015+ things being worked around there:

- Property spread, and
- Computed property syntax in object literals (`[key]: value`)